# Omniauth, Twitter: OAuth::Unauthorized / 401 Unauthorized upon callback from Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I get the error `OAuth::Unauthorized` / `401 Unauthorized` when my Twitter app does the callback.

- I'm using:

  ```
  gem 'omniauth'         # (1.2.1)
  gem 'omniauth-twitter' # (1.0.1)
  gem 'rails', '4.1.0.rc1'
  ```
- The callback URL submitted for the Twitter app (tried both solutions):

  - a bit.ly URL pointing to: `http://127.0.0.1:3000`
  - or: the direct URL: `http://127.0.0.1:3000`
- The called callback URL looks like:

  ```
  http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=FcU...hYFk&oauth_verifier=Dge...oJ27E
  ```
- routes.rb:

  ```
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'mycontroller#create'
  get '/auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  ```
- my machine's time is OK, as explained here: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/FAQ
- my initializers/omniauth.rb looks like this:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :twitter, 'e93Q89eW4o...DNMe9w3i8tqQ', 'owERioaRjj...jrKdotiiOeIUdd89irlA'
  end
  ```

What am I missing?

EDIT - Some trace:

`` OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:18:in `get_access_token'
  omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:57:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue:

This block was defined 2x inside my app:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

  provider :twitter, 'e93Q89eW4o...DNMe9w3i8tqQ', 'owERioaRjj...jrKdotiiOeIUdd89irlA'

end
```

Make sure you set this only 1x !

(If you have the habit of copying over config files from previous projects, you risk ending up with duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same error. However, my solution is different since I only declared the block once in my app.

I follow FAQ from github: intridea/omniauth and solved my problem by making the system clock correct. Once i changed to the correct time, I can succesfully using twitter omniauth login.

Hope it contributes to answer this question